# Regex to match string with five forward slashes

Tags: regex

I want to write a regex to match any string with 5 forward slashes in. This is to match a URL in Google Analytics. I thought I had gotten close, but no cigar yet. This is what I've come up with:

```
\/.*\/.*\/.*\/.*\/.*$
```

But it doesn't match anything. How can I correct this? Or is it not possible?

Comment: Could you provide a test input? Also, `.*$` seems rather pointless to me since you don't seem to be using capture groups... Why not just leave it off and allow a mid-string match? Your particular regex engine might also be relevant.

Comment: http://www.regexpal.com/

Comment: What is your regex flavor?

Comment: What are you trying to do?
Do you want only forward slashes in the string??
Or do you want a string which has five forward slashes for sure?

Comment: Do you need exactly 5 slashes, so no more and no less? Furthermore, please provide input which does not behave as expected, and let us know what you expect and how it behaves.

Comment: Yes, exactly five slashes. I'm not 100% sure which regex engine Google Analytics uses, I can't find it online anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following regex [will work](https://regex101.com/r/aE3wN2/1):

```regex
.*(?:\/.*){5}
```

Explanation:

```
.*             # Any character (except newlines) 0 or more times
   (?:         # Start of non-capturing group
      \/       # Matches `/` literally (is esacped with a backslash)
        .*     # Any character (except newlines) 0 or more times
          )    # End of group
           {5} # The previous group five times
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want just something like /aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/, this will make the trick: /[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+/
However, there are more things to consider?

1. Is this the only format accepted?
2. Is it possible to have any chain of characters before the first slash?
3. Is it possible to have any chain of characters after the last slash?

If this one doesn't fit your needs, you as might as well provide some valid and invalid inputs.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "(\w*\W){5}", because "\W" is for non-word chars.

Answer (score 0):

Simple like this:

```
(/[^/]*){5}
```

Change * to + if you need at least a character between slashes.

Answer (score 0):

I need to pull out links only have just string with excluding numbers and queries in URL in Google Analytics.

so, I need this URL

www.site.com/en/rent/cairo/apartments-for-rent/

and exclude these

```
www.website.com/en/buy/apartment-for-sale-in-acacia-compound-new-cairo-947145/

  www.website.com/en/buy/apartment-for-sale-in-acacia-compound-new-cairo-947145/?price=1000
```