# Regex expression to match forward slash followed by string

Tags: regex, powershell, powershell-3.0

I need to filter a string, if it contains three strings:

```
/A/ABC
A_ABC
Downloaded
```

I have two types of lines. All contain `Downloaded`, but only either `/A/ABC` or `A_ABC`

Every substring has spaces to their left and right.

What are the correct regex expressions to match a line, if it contains `Downloaded` and `ABC`?

My big problem to match for `ABC` are either the slash or underscore on its left side.

I tried the following expression:

```
'\bDownloaded\b + \b/A/ABC\b | \/ABC\b'
```

However I don't receive the matching lines. Maybe someone has an easy fix to my try. Thank you!

`/A/` and `A_` are only examples. There could be any other letter or multiple letters. I just need to know if there is ABC anywhere in the line.

To be clear: I checked several [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34162376/regex-to-match-string-with-five-forward-slashes), which were close to my problem, but couldn't finally solve mine.

Comment: Should they be in that order?

Comment: Usually, lookaheads are used: `'^(?=.*/A/ABC\b)(?=.*\bA_ABC\b)(?=.*\bDownloaded\b)'` if you want to check for the strings inside a string in any order. Do not add `\b` before `/` unless you expect a match only after a letter, digit or `_`.

Comment: Guys please check my edit, I explained my problem a bit wrong. Sorry!

Comment: ```/A/``` and ```A_``` are only examples. There could be any other letter or multiple letters. I just need to know if there is ABC anywhere in the line.

Comment: If `Downloaded` is followed with the other two, use `\bDownloaded\b.*(?:/A/ABC|\bA_ABC)\b'`. Please add examples you want to match and avoid matching.

Comment: If the order of Downloaded and the ABC can vary and ABC can be between other characters as well, you could use the lookaheads  Wiktor Stribiżew suggested, maybe like `^(?=.*\bDownloaded\b).*ABC.*`

Comment: @Thefourthbird If you like to have the gems, your suggestion worked perfectly :)

Comment: That is kind of you, but it was the first suggestion of @WiktorStribiżew so if he wants to post it that is also ok with me.

Comment: @Thefourthbird Please post the answer, I was unsure and still am what OP needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a positive lookahead and assert the word `Downloaded`, then match `ABC` in the string

```
^(?=.*\bDownloaded\b).*ABC.*$
```

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%3f%3d.*%5cbDownloaded%5cb%29.*ABC.*%24&i=Downloaded+%2fA%2fABC+and+A_ABC)

That will match:

- `^` Assert start of the string
- `(?=.*\bDownloaded\b)` Positive [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), assert what follows is the word Downloaded between word boundaries
- `.*ABC.*` Match any character 0+ times, then `ABC` followed by any character 0+ times
- `$` Assert end of string